# タブ文字をgrepしたい

Tags: unix, grep

Unix環境で、タブ文字（`"\t"`）を `grep` するにはどうすれば良いですか？

`grep "\\t"` や `grep '\t'` だと `t` で検索されてしまい上手くいきませんでした。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash であれば、シングルクォートの前にドル記号を入れた `$'...'` 形式の文字列の中に `\t` を入れると Bash がタブ文字として解釈してくれます。

```
grep $'\t'
```

参考

- Bash マニュアル [3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)
- 英語版 Stack Overflow の質問 ["grep a tab in UNIX"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825552/5989200) に対する [antimirov さんの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694596/5989200)

Answer (score 3):

`grep $'\t'`の方がスマートですが他の制御コードにも使える方法です。

```
grep "$(echo -n -e \\x09)"
```

昔風の書き方なら

```
grep "`echo -n -e \\\x09`"
```

試した環境
GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
grep (GNU grep) 3.1

Comment: シェルによっては(`dash` や `posh` など) `echo`(シェルのビルトインコマンド)に `-e` オプションが無かったりしますので、`grep "$(printf '\t')"` の方が無難でしょう。

Comment: metropolis さん、コメントありがとうございます。 ※これまでは、printfが外部コマンドのため使うことをためらっていましたが、今試したら「シェル組み込み関数」になっていました。いったいいつの間に？printf版を回答として投稿してもらえれば後々役にたつ回答になると思いますがいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

もし、ターミナル上での話であれば(シェルが起動していてコマンド待ち状態であれば)、
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> → <kbd>Tab</kbd> の順番でキー入力すればタブ文字が直接入力できます。
この方法はbashでない多くのシェルで適用できると思います。

```
$ grep '[CTRL+v][TAB]' files*
```

(見た目上はスペースとタブの区別はつかないのでターミナル上では下のような感じに見えます。)

```
$ grep '  ' files*
```

シェルスクリプトの中で使用するのならエディタ上でスペースとタブは区別しづらかったり、
タブ→スペース変換等で誤って消されてしまう可能性があるので、
おすすめしません。
他の方が回答している方法でやるのが良いかと思います。