# 最近近傍法のC言語プログラミング

Tags: c

このサイトで前回テキストについての質問をさせていただいたので、そのURLを以下に貼り付けます。
[テキストから各列の最小値を読み込んで、それらの数値を足していくプログラム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73143/%e3%83%86%e3%82%ad%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e5%90%84%e5%88%97%e3%81%ae%e6%9c%80%e5%b0%8f%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7-%e3%81%9d%e3%82%8c%e3%82%89%e3%81%ae%e6%95%b0%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e8%b6%b3%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0)

前回質問した時、今回のことに関連するサイト"traveling salesman problem greedy algorithm C program"
に入って、色々似ているプログラムを見つけたので、それを参考にここ数日考え、以下のようにプログラムをしたのですが、実行は出来るものの、結果がかなり期待するものとは異なってしまいました

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int FNLEN=50;          /* ファイル名の長さ */
const int MAX_CITY=100;      /* 都市数最大値 */

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int i,j,ncity,dept;
  int visit[MAX_CITY];  /* 0: 未訪問、1: 訪問済み (訪問したかどうか)*/
  int visit_list[MAX_CITY];  /* 訪問順 */
  double dist[MAX_CITY][MAX_CITY],total_dist,min_dist;
  char file_name[FNLEN];  /* データファイル名 */
    
  printf("Data file name: ");
  scanf("%s",file_name);
    
  if ((fp = fopen(file_name,"r")) == NULL){  /* ファイルオープンに失敗した場合は終了 */
    printf("%s: ファイルをオープンできません!\n",file_name);
    return -1;
  }

  /* ファイルからデータを読み込む　*/
  printf("データファイル名:   %s\n",file_name);
  fscanf(fp,"%d",&ncity);  /* 都市数の読み込み */
  
  if (ncity > MAX_CITY){
    printf("都市の数は%3d以下にしてください！\n",MAX_CITY);
    return -1;
  }
  
  for (i=0;i<ncity;i++){   /* 距離行列の読み込み */
    for (j=0;j<ncity;j++){
      fscanf(fp,"%lf",&dist[i][j]);
      printf("%10.3lf",dist[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
        
  fclose(fp);  /* ファイルクローズ */

  /* 出発する都市の都市番号をキーボード入力 */
  printf("出発地の都市番号(1--%3d)を入力して下さい。  ",ncity);
  scanf("%d", &dept);
  if (dept > ncity || dept < 0){
    printf("都市番号が無効です。\n");
    return(-1);
  }
  
  /* 配列 visit および visit_list の初期化 */
  for (i=0;i<ncity;i++){
    visit[i]=0;
    visit_list[i] = -1;
  }
    
  /* ---- 貪欲算法 start ---- */
  double min,cost;
  printf("順回路は\n");
  for(i=dept;i<ncity;i++){
    for(j=dept;j<ncity;j++){
    if(dist[i][j]!=0) 
      if(dist[i][j]<min){
          min=dist[i][j];
          printf("%d ",j);
          cost+=min;
      } 
     }
   }
   printf("総移動距離は%fです。\n",cost);       
  /* ---- 貪欲算法 end ---- */
    
   return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
Data file name: euro.txt
データファイル名:   euro.txt
     0.000   340.000  1270.000  1450.000  2400.000   780.000
   340.000     0.000  1060.000  1120.000  2100.000   490.000
  1270.000  1060.000     0.000  1370.000  2370.000  1250.000
  1450.000  1120.000  1370.000     0.000  1040.000   700.000
  2400.000  2100.000  2370.000  1040.000     0.000  1620.000
   780.000   490.000  1250.000   700.000  1620.000     0.000
出発地の都市番号(1--  6)を入力して下さい。  1
順回路は
総移動距離は0.000000です。
```

期待する実行結果

```
ata file name: euro.txt
データファイル名:   euro.txt     
0.000   340.000  1270.000  1450.000  2400.000   780.000   
340.000     0.000  1060.000  1120.000  2100.000   490.000  
1270.000  1060.000     0.000  1370.000  2370.000  1250.000  
1450.000  1120.000  1370.000     0.000  1040.000   700.000  
2400.000  2100.000  2370.000  1040.000     0.000  1620.000   
780.000   490.000  1250.000   700.000  1620.000     0.000
出発地の都市番号(1--  6)を入力して下さい。  1
巡回路は    1    2    6    4    5    3    1
総移動距離は  6210.000です。
```

このように、期待する実行結果とは順回路と総距離の部分で出力が違います。
プログラミング歴四ヶ月程度の自分なりにはかなり考えたのですが、自分的にはこれ以上は思いつきませんでした。
不明な点、修正すべき点があれば、それをどのように修正すればいいのか教えてくれるととても助かります。

Comment: [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)を熟読してください。「前回のテキスト課題についての続きの質問」という質問タイトルは閲覧者にとって何の情報も含んでいません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。条件を完璧に満たしているかはわかりませんが、質問タイトルを編集しました。

Comment: 「実行は出来るものの、結果がかなり期待するものとは異なってしまいました」とありますが、どのように期待していて、出た結果がどう違ったのか明記されたほうが回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: 編集しました。また、期待する実行結果などは、URL「テキストから各列の最小値を読み込んで、それらの数値を足していくプログラム」にも記載済みです。

Comment: 例え過去の質問と関連するものであっても、個々の投稿を見れば内容が把握できるように質問を構成すべきです。 ("XXX に書いてあるから読んでください" は、読み手に取って不親切です。)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visit` や `visit_list` 配列が使われていないので、「巡回」という事を誤って解釈しているのではないでしょうか。

以下に変更箇所だけ載せておきます(ごく単純な greedy algorithm の実装例になります)。

```c
// import DBL_MAX
#include <float.h>
            :

  /* 出発する都市の都市番号をキーボード入力 */
  printf("出発地の都市番号(1--%3d)を入力して下さい。  ",ncity);
  scanf("%d", &dept);
  if (dept > ncity || dept <= 0){
    printf("都市番号が無効です。\n");
    return(-1);
  }
  dept--; // 入力値は 1-base, 配列の index は 0-base

  /* 配列 visit の初期化 */
  for (i=0;i<ncity;i++)
    visit[i] = 0;
  visit[dept] = 1;  // 1: 訪問済

  /* ---- 貪欲算法 start ---- */
  double min, cost;
  int min_idx;
  printf("順回路は\n");
  printf("%d ", dept+1);
  i = dept;
  while(i >= 0) {
    min = DBL_MAX;
    min_idx = -1;
    for(j=0;j<ncity;j++){
      if (i != j && !visit[j]) {
        if(dist[i][j] < min){
          min = dist[i][j];
          min_idx = j;
        }
      }
    }

    if (min_idx < 0) { // 全ての地点を訪問済
      printf("%d\n", dept+1);
      cost += dist[i][dept];
    } else {
      printf("%d ", min_idx+1);
      cost += min;
      visit[min_idx] = 1;
    }
    i = min_idx;
  }
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。このプログラムを読んで、プログラミングの理解を深めていきたいです。また、もし新たに貪欲算法のプログラミング課題が出た時は、このプログラムを理解した上で実装していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* ---- 貪欲算法 start ---- */
  double min,cost;
```

と`min`を初期化せずに使用されているので

```
      if(dist[i][j]<min){
          min=dist[i][j];
          printf("%d ",j);
          cost+=min;
      }
```

このifブロックに入れないだけではないでしょうか。
この場合、何で初期化すればよいかですが、適当な値を入れるより、読み込んだ値の中の最大値を入れておけば良いと思います。

Comment: ブロックに入れないだけとは、if文の中くらいカッコ｛｝を外せということでしょうか。とりあえずやってみましたが、全く異なる実行結果となりました。（minは初期化しました。）

Comment: すみません、言葉がたりませんでした。ifの条件がdist[i][j]がminより小さいときのみ実行することになっている為、minを初期化していないと、不定値＝何が入っているか判らない状態となってマイナスと解釈されることもあり得ると思います。なので、意図した結果にならないのは「ifの条件を満たす値がないためブロック内の処理を実行できていないだけ」という意味で書きました。